# Footer doesn't align with header and menubar

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble with the footer's alignment. Everything is ok at the left side but not on the right side. The footer hasn't no little gap like the header or menubar.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id="header">
    <a href="#">
        <center>
            <p>LOGO HERE...</p>
        </center>
    </a>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<footer id="footer">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2016 - All rights reserved</p>
    LOREM IPSUM
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

my CSS:

```
#footer {
    background-color: darkblue;
    bottom: 1px;
    color: white;
    height: 8vh;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

I've tested this code with Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer -- always the same 'issue'. But I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Try this remove width: 100% and add left: 0 and right: 0 instead

Answer (score 0):

It's because of predefined paddings/margins. Please add this css rule:

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This is a simple reset. I recommend you to [read this about css resets](http://cssreset.com/)

Check it in a snippet:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#header{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
#footer {
    background-color: darkblue;
    bottom: 1px;
    color: white;
    height: 8vh;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <a href="#">
        <center>
            <p>LOGO HERE...</p>
        </center>
    </a>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">MENU-Item#1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<footer id="footer">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2016 - All rights reserved</p>
    LOREM IPSUM
</footer>
```

Comment: Hey Chris, I think you've got me wrong: I want the left and right gap. So I need a solution for the footer's right gap.